# after login redirect does not work facebook cakephp

Tags: facebook, cakephp

I am integrating [webtechnick facebook plugin](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin) , my cake version is 2.3.1. When I click Facebook login button, the fb window appears, and when I type my fb email and password it disappears, but does not refresh the page, I have specified the redirect page like

```
public function afterFacebookLogin() {
    $this->redirect ( '/posts' );
}
```

The interesting thing, that when after this, I one time manually refresh the page, it already redirects to `/posts` page and also I can see that the user is logged in.

THanks

Comment: Can you post the code from your View that contains the Facebook login button?

Comment: where do you call the afterFacebookLogin() function?